# Eclipse : Why the web project is not shown under web apps folder if deployed through Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE (JUno Version )

In Eclipse IDE server tab , i have configured Tomcat 7 , then created a new Dynamic Web Project and then added Web Project  to TOmcat server in server tab through Add and Remove Option .

Please see the Screen shot below

My question is why could i am not able to see my Web Project under webapps folder in Tomcat server ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Eclipse tells Tomcat to look for the webapp in the directory where Eclipse compiles the webapp, in order to avoid unnecessary file copies and be able to change the content of a JSP and have the result be immediately available without needing to redeploy everything.

It speeds things up significantly.

Comment: great answer , if you dont mind , how can we know the path / directory where  Eclipse compiles the webapp ??

Comment: It's the target directory of the project (`bin` by default). Also look at the server.xml file in eclipse. You'll find the entry where the webapp is declared.